# How to modify the opacity from an image in my leaflet code

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a png image and I want to overlap it with my map. Doing this is easy,

```
var db = [ 39.512255848479349, 2.655340655173929 ];
var ir = [ 39.650654877825758, 2.476488395145371 ];

var imageUrl = '/static/js/block_L0_X0_Y1.png',
imageBounds = [db,ir];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
// Recopilamos todo y lo mostramos en el mapa
var marker = L.marker(coo, {icon: iconMarker}).bindPopup(popUp);
layerGroup.addLayer(marker);
map.addLayer(layerGroup);
```

The problem is that now this image completely covers the map. For this, I thought change the opacity of the image but is not working. What I'm doing wrong? Here is the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#imageoverlay-opacity).

```
var db = [ 39.512255848479349, 2.655340655173929 ];
var ir = [ 39.650654877825758, 2.476488395145371 ];

var imageUrl = '/static/js/block_L0_X0_Y1.png',
imageBounds = [db,ir];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, opacity=0.5).addTo(map);
// Recopilamos todo y lo mostramos en el mapa
var marker = L.marker(coo, {icon: iconMarker}).bindPopup(popUp);
layerGroup.addLayer(marker);
map.addLayer(layerGroup);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please try `L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity: 0.5}).addTo(map);`

Comment: I tried explaining it, so you might understand it better. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses 'wrong' JavaScript syntax.

```
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, opacity=0.5).addTo(map);
```

The only times where you'd want to do `variable = 0.5` is when you want to change a JavaScript variable's value. In this case, you want to send data to another function. This is usually done in a JavaScript Object format.

So changing your options to an object should work:

```
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds, {opacity: 0.5}).addTo(map);
```